# nginx - how to route a specific uri endpoint without having it ending with a slash

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

my current setup:

1. user inputs [www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck](http://www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck)
2. kubernetes traefik ingress with backend as /example and goes to a nginx service
3. nginx with this small configuration:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;


    location /example/xx/healthcheck {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index output.html;
    }
```

i placed output.html inside /usr/share/nginx/html/example/xx/healthcheck

My issue is that when i hit [www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck](http://www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck) it doesn't load the page. it only works if it has a slash at the end
[www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck/](http://www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck/)

is there a proper and better way to do this? I want [www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck](http://www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck) and it hits the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
location = /example/xx/healthcheck {
    default_type text/html;
    alias /any/path/to/output.html;
}
```

Beware - the slash-ended request `www.example.com/example/xx/healthcheck/` won't work anymore with this config, although it would work if you use your `location /example/xx/healthcheck { ... }` as the second one or use a rewrite rule like

```
rewrite ^/example/xx/healthcheck/$ /example/xx/healthcheck;
```

Comment: I tried that just now but it downloads the file instead of showing the file in the browser. Is there a way to display the content in the browser?
Thanks!

Comment: @sdas2 Sorry, didn't thought about that `location` block would use the default mime type (usually `application/octet-stream`). Updated the answer.

Comment: i used this
```
location  /example/xx/healthcheck {
    alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/output.html;
    default_type application/octet-stream; 
}
```
I restarted the pod and it still downloads the file.

is that default type wrong?

Comment: @sdas2 I said that I updated the answer. Don't you notice the answer have been edited? `application/octet-stream` is the default MIME type, it should be changed to `text/html`.

Comment: @sdas2 I used `location = /example/xx/healthcheck { ... }`, not the `location /example/xx/healthcheck { ... }`

Comment: yea sorry, i noticed the edit after. I will try now.

Comment: I have another question now but i think i will make another post.
it's related to returning a 404 or 403 status when it hits this endpoint.

Comment: @sdas2 The StackOverflow way of "thank you" described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) :)

Comment: i did upvote it and i get this msg
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @sdas2 I know that, I talking about accepting the answer, not upvoting it.